# Can't understand subset creator

Tags: python, recursion

New with programming and spend a lot of time on trying to understand this recursive function, but I just can't visualize it. It's about the `subsetsRecur` function. Anyone have a simple understandable explanation?

```
class py_solution:

    def sub_sets(self, sset):
        return self.subsetsRecur([], sorted(sset))

    def subsetsRecur(self, current, sset):
        if sset:
            return self.subsetsRecur(current, sset[1:]) + self.subsetsRecur(current + [sset[0]], sset[1:])
        return [current]
print(py_solution().sub_sets([4,5,6]))
```

Comment: Just add a `print` statement and you'll see how everything evolves.

Answer (score 1):

The code calculates the *powerset* of a given set. It is a direct implementation of a standard recursive algorithm. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) for the definition of the algorithm